# Contar personas de un rango en excel

Tags: excel, vba

Necesito de su ayuda. Tengo este archivo de excel que me trae nombres de otros archivos con código de vba y los pone como lista, de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que generar en otra hoja unas tablas que cuenten los empleados que aparecen esas listas por archivos. Esta es la tabla que cuenta los empleados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el codigo que tengo de la tabla:

```
Dim item As Variant
Dim item1 As Variant
Dim UltimaLinea
Dim x As Double
Dim ult As Double
Dim ult2 As Double
Dim nameResult As Range
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim TargetCell As Range

'Asignamos los valores
Set SourceRange = Sheets("Concentrado").Range("B3:B100")
Set TargetCell = Sheets("Resumen").Range("B3:B100")
'Set nameResult = Sheets("Resumen").Range("H6:H11")

'Copiamos los valores y los filtramos por unicos valores
SourceRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=TargetCell, Unique:=True

'ult para el criterio a buscar
ult = Worksheets("Resumen").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'ult2 para el conjunto de datos a contar
ult2 = Worksheets("Concentrado").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'x a partir de que celda ejecutar el For
For x = 2 To ult

    Dato = Worksheets("Resumen").Cells(x, 2).Value
    respuesta = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Concentrado").Range("B3:B" & ult2), Dato)
    Sheets("Resumen").Cells(x, 3).Value = respuesta

Next x
```

Ok entonces lo que necesito es un código que me genere esa tabla pero por cada archivo, y esa tabla que genero, la vaya pegando en alguna parte de la hoja haga un salto de celda y genere la tabla de la siguiente lista y así sucesivamente (O si hay una mejor opción tambien).
Este código lo hace de toda la columna, necesito uno que me genere por cada archivo (cabe mencionar que la lista le puse espacios en blanco para separar entre cada archivo los datos y poder identificarlos.)

No me sale por que en esta parte del codigo, no se como poner la parte del Range para indicarle desde que parte iniciar y terminar para cada parte separada de la lista

```
respuesta = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Concentrado").Range("B3:B" & ult2), Dato)
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Se los agradezco!

Comment: Creo que lo mejor es que te lleves cada subconjunto a un diccionario y lo vayas procesando. Y luego generes el output en hojas diferentes (aunque también se podría si quieres generarlos en la misma). La ventaja de usar diccionarios es que solo admiten valores únicos. Podrías asociar a cada valor cuántas veces aparece